# Can't make dropdown work

Tags: html, css

I've this dropdown, to make it work, i see only one solution is taking off the **overflow**, but if i take it it stays like this:

[image]

but if i apply an overflow: hidden it stays like this:

[image]

How can i make this work. I've tried to apply **overflow: hidden;** in other div but dosen't work.

Link to website: http://store01.titus.biz/

```
<div class="span12 horizontal-category" style="overflow: hidden">                                 
       <span class="carousel-prev disabled" id="carousel-category-prev"></span>
       <ul class="nav myCustomNav">       
    <li class="dropdown"></li>
        ... </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use clipping. First remove the overflow on div.span12.horizontal-category. Then add a clip rect on the div that is between the 2 control buttons #carousel-category-prev, #carousel-category-next. The position of absolute is required to use clipping however. But this should be fine.

```
<div class="span12 horizontal-category">
    <span id="carousel-category-prev" class="carousel-prev disabled"></span>
    <div  style="position: absolute; clip: rect(auto, auto, 500px, auto);"></div>
    <span id="carousel-category-next" class="carousel-next"></span>
</div>
```

This should clip the overflow on the left and right. Then increase the bottom (500px) to whatever value you need it to be. Clipping is a way to control how the overflow works.

Comment: It is really unfortunate that the clipping property only works on absolutely position elements. It is a very useful CSS property for controlling overflow. But this requirements makes it unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

This will maybe help you:

Remove **overflow:hidden** from `class="span12 horizontal-category"`.
Add **overflow:hidden** to `class="main-container"`.

And you could give control buttons, like `../img/button-prev-disabled.png` a white background, so you can't see the corners of the menu when it slides to left and right.

Answer (score 0):

I have a try, first make the ul have enough height to display the dropdown menu, then apply `margin-top: -xxxpx` to the element below the ul.

I test the follow code in my Chrome:

1. edit `margin-bottom: 200px;` to `.horizontal-category ul`
2. add `margin-top: -180px;` to `.ei-slider`

This way don't need CSS3 , so it's more compatibility. Test it!